# getting value from the combobox and textbox inside listview

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

What I have is a `ListView` with `TextBlock` columns, a `ComboBox` column and `TextBox` column.  What I want to do is get the values from the rows selected which contains the text block, combo box and text box.  I am able to get the values from the `TextBlock` using :

```
string id = (listView1.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView).Row[0].ToString();//works
```

but not able to get the values from the combo box and textbox.

Can anybody help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get hold of the item container that represents your selected row.

It'll be something like:

```
listView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView1.SelectedItems[i]);
```

Once you have the Control that represents your row, you should be able to access its logical tree.